# How to reinstall an uninstalled system app through ADB?

Tags: adb, installation, uninstallation, system-apps

My phone is an unrooted Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge running Oreo 8.0. Yesterday when removing bloatware from my phone, I accidentally uninstalled a system app using the adb command:

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0
```

I suspect the culprit to be `com.sec.factory.camera`, as since that unfortunate event, the camera app crashes every time I try to launch it.

I tried reinstalling it using either of these two commands

```
pm install com.sec.factory.camera
pm install --user 0 com.sec.factory.camera
```

but they returned a "can't open non-file" error message.

I tried as well downloading the APK on my phone and installing it from Android, but at the end of the installation process, I got a "not installed application" message.

How to reinstall an uninstalled system app through ADB?

Comment: The app must still be there somewhere inside /system, so try finding its absolute location and  installing from there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Technically, the command `adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 <package_name>` does not uninstall an app from the device. Instead, it just removes it from a user.

There are a couple of ways to get the removed app back to the user: one way is through an ADB shell with the command:

```
adb shell cmd package install-existing <package_name>
```

Or an extreme way would be through a factory reset of the device.

Comment: I get `unkown command: install-existing`

Comment: Depending on the OS/terminal, the command after `adb shell` and `cmd` might need to be enclosed with quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled the package `com.google.android.partnersetup` when I was going to uninstall other app. I couldn't recover it with [Bo Lawson's method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215316/44325). Instead, I found this way:

```
pm dump com.google.android.partnersetup | grep Path
```

This gives us some paths. One of them is the one I'm going to use:
*"**codePath=**/system/priv-app/GooglePartnerSetup"*

Finally, I install the app which is in that direction. The app has the same name of the app folder, with ".apk" at the end:

```
pm install -r --user 0 /system/priv-app/GooglePartnerSetup/GooglePartnerSetup.apk
```

I hope this helps, but I don't know what exactly does this do.

My source: [comment from Mac23](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-get-install-back-uninstalled-apps-apks-with-adb.3894235/page-4#post-84291287).

Answer (score 3):

For those circumstances when `install-existing` solution is unavailable the [dandan657's](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/236011/370150) method works. But I've found an easier way to look for the location of the existing APK. In ADB shell type:

```
pm list packages -f -u | grep <package name>
```

You will get the result in this format:

```
package:<full path to the apk>=<package name>
```

Example:

```
package:/system/app/Photos/Photos.apk=com.google.android.apps.photos
```

These are the useful optional parameters that `pm list packages` command accepts:

```
-f: See their associated file.
-d: Filter to only show disabled packages.
-e: Filter to only show enabled packages.
-s: Filter to only show system packages.
-3: Filter to only show third party packages.
-i: See the installer for the packages.
-u: Also include uninstalled packages.
--user <USER_ID>: The user space to query.
```

**Tip**: Using the above it might be a good idea to have variously filtered package lists saved for the future reference.

Reference: https://android-doc.github.io/tools/help/shell.html#pm

Answer (score 2):

My way

1. Install Solid Explorer
2. Open Settings
3. Enable Root Storage
4. Back to main
5. Open hamburger menu
6. Select root
7. Go to system
8. Go to app
9. Search your app
10. Install it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Android 6 phone. On Android 6, the `adb shell cmd ...` commands are not available.

I fixed it the following way (needs root or custom recovery with full file system access):

1. Locate the APK file of the deleted package in the `/system/priv-app` folder
2. Move the APK file to a different location (e.g. `/data/app`)
3. Reboot phone
4. Move the APK file back to its original location
5. Reboot phone

I hope this can help others who also don't have Android 7 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

[Bo Lawson's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215316/44325) has worked perfectly and is the best answer for those without root access, this is what I did:

Install the app again by:

```
adb shell cmd package install-existing <package-name>
```

Then uninstall it by:

```
adb shell pm uninstall <package-name>
```

Then install the app or its update from Google Play or from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally uninstalled the default file manager and then was unable to set shared dirs for new apps and other essential functions.

Once I found out the package name included `documentsui`, searching for that in [App Manager](https://muntashirakon.github.io/AppManager/) (free, available on F-Droid) allowed me to just click a greyed-out listing, where it then asked me whether I wanted to reinstall it. Full functionality restored.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).