# Can you install Google Play Store with adb after it was uninstalled?

Tags: google-play-store, adb, installation, 9.0-pie

I have a non-rooted Samsung phone that runs android version 9 as shown in the image below.

[image]

Some time ago I uninstalled Google Play Store from my phone because I thought that I could reinstall it if needed. I used the following command:

`adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.vending`

Now I want to install Google Play Store again. I downloaded an apk file for Google Play Store from apkmirror which can be found [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-33-1-16-release/google-play-store-33-1-16-19-0-pr-487270566-android-apk-download/). I tried to install Google Play Store again by issuing the adb install command with the name of the downloaded apk file:

`adb -s 5200088af0785579 install com.android.vending_33.1.16-19_0_PR_487270566-83311600_minAPI19_maxAPI24\(armeabi-v7a\,x86\,x86_64\)\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk`.

When the command is executed I get the message that the streamed install was successful as shown in the image below. After I searched my phone for Google Play Store, I couldn't find it anywhere, including my Google folder and Apps list. I also looked at disabled apps. If I try to uninstall the apk version of Google Play Store with `adb uninstall com.android.vending` I get the message that the uninstall was successful, indicating that it was indeed installed on my phone. I just don't know how to access it. Issuing the uninstall command again gives an error as shown in the image below.

[image]

Is it even possible to install Google Play Store after uninstalling it? Am I using the correct apk file? Are there some additional steps I should take to make it work? Or is there an alternative method I could use to reinstall it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215313/how-to-reinstall-an-accidentally-uninstalled-app-through-adb The PlayStore app package name is `com.android.vending`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it in the end. You must specify the user for which you are installing it with `--user USER_ID`. The USER_ID for the main/primary user is 0. After adding this argument to the installation command, Play Store was successfully installed and accessible on my phone.

`adb -s 5200088af0785579 install --user 0 com.android.vending_33.1.16-19_0_PR_487270566-83311600_minAPI19_maxAPI24\(armeabi-v7a\,x86\,x86_64\)\(nodpi\)_apkmirror.com.apk`

EDIT:
Although I managed to install it with the command shown above, Google Play Store keeps crashing.

@Robert The solution proposed in the question you linked actually works. Just for clarity, here is the full command that solved my problem.

`adb shell cmd package install-existing com.android.vending`

Comment: A bummer that this question was closed, but for future readers: Make sure to install gsf too, or it will **crash**. In total, there are three essential apps to make the Google Play Store work: `com.google.android.gsf`, `com.google.android.gms` and `com.android.vending`. Install them by typing `adb shell` and then: `pm install-existing packagename` (repeat that last part replacing packagename with the name of the three mentioned apps above). After that, restart your phone for good measure.