# Samsung Galaxy Tab A enable system app for other profile?

Tags: android-11, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

I created a non-admin new user on this tablet. It initially prompts to select Samsung system apps, e.g. Samsung branded calendar, calculator, etc. I didn't care about any of those so, with the exception of camera (because I know camera apps can be tightly bound to specific devices) I disabled them all. I setup the whole profile, google apps, other apps, logged into to them all, y'know, all the "new setup" stuff.

Unfortunately, I discovered that this camera app can only launch the Samsung Gallery system app. Fine, I'll allow that... But how? There seems to be absolutely no way to enable this app after initially disabling it. The admin profile can't reselect the system apps for the other profiles anywhere. The new profile can't install it from the Galaxy Store. I acquired the APK, but the install failed (yes, unknown sources was allowed).

What the heck? I really don't want to nuke this profile because of this annoyance. Anyway other things to try? Is there a compatible and/or better camera app?

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [How to reinstall an accidentally uninstalled (system) app through ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215313/44325). While the linked question is about "uninstalled apps", I think the situation is similar since the app is still installed on the device but removed (not installed) on another user.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewT. Some good things to try there. I may get around to it. At the end of the day, not being able to change the Camera Gallery shortcut to Google Photos annoyed me, so I just installed OpenCamera. It's a "good enough" solution. I tried a GCam port, but that didn't work. Oh well.